# Imhist in matlab does not display the histogram

Tags: matlab

I have an image named boat stored in a .mat file (Boat.mat)
I loaded the file using `load('Boat.mat')`
If I type `imshow(boat)` it just displays a blank box.
I can only view the image with `imshow(boat,[0 255])`.
When I use `imhist(boat)` I again get a blank box. How do I see the histogram. I need to see the histogram. Also I am not able to use `histeq(boat)` for histogram equalization.

Any help will be appreciated.
Thanks

Here is the link to the Boat.mat file
http://www.engr.colostate.edu/ECE513/SP11/Boat.mat

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By default, `imshow` assumes a floating-point image with values between 0 and 1, which is why your image (with values from 0 to 255) appears entirely as white - all the values are greater than 1.  As you found, you can force `imshow` to scale the values differently but it is probably easier if you just rescale the image first, and keep it like that:

```
boatDbl = boat / 255;

figure;
imshow(boatDbl);

figure;
imhist(boatDbl);
```

**EDIT:** As Shai has pointed out below, this happens is because `imshow` and others predict the range of values based the datatype of the matrix - since your `boat` matrix is a `double`, they assume the range 0 to 1.  Therefore an alternative fix is to convert the matrix to an `integer` type, which will make `imshow` assume a range of 0 to 255:

```
boat = uint8(boat);
```

Answer (score 0):

Regarding the `imhist(image)` part, you might want to try converting the image to grayscale first (even if it was originally a grayscale image), as follows:

```
newImage = rgb2gray(oldImage);
```

After, you should be able to perform the `imhist(newImage)` without any problems. Let me know if it works!

Comment: Under which conditions will this work? Why would it work? Won't this give you an error if the image is already a single channel? This answer raises more questions than it answers and really doesn't warrant posting on a 5 year old question.